# SQL Server how to select two result sets with the second overlapping the first set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

First, my apologies for the lengthy and somewhat confusing title, allow me to elaborate.

I have an online store that sells cards for birthdays, xmas, etc. and currently it offers a selection of default cards that can be chosen by the user.

I plan to let the users modify the existing cards (changing it's layout, text, coloring etc.) but I want to retain the default card and record which card the modification came from. This part I think I have figured out already.

My goal is to have the website display all default cards to the user but display the user's own replacement cards in place of the default from which it came.

With that in mind, my database table has the following partial layout:

```
Table: Cards
UserId   int
CardId   int
CardText int
```

Let's say the default cards are stored under UserId 1 and the new user is UserId 2, the records for the above table would appear as follows:

```
UserId CardId CardText
  1      1    Valentines
  1      2    Birthday
  1      3    Merry Xmas
  2      1    Be my valentine
```

As you can see, User #2 has modified Card #1 changing the text from "Valentines" to "Be my valentines" and the original Card #1 for User #1 is still available for future users.

I want to display all default cards but display the users replacement card in place of its default counterpart card.

This means UserId 1 would see:

```
CardId 1 [UserId #1]
CardId 2 [UserId #1]
CardId 3 [UserId #1]
```

And UserId 2 would see:

```
CardId 1 [UserId #2]  <-
CardId 2 [UserId #1]
CardId 3 [UserId #1]
```

Now to the MSSQL. The obvious solution would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM CARDS
WHERE UserId = 1
AND CardId NOT IN (SELECT CardId FROM CARDS WHERE UserId = 2)
     UNION
SELECT * FROM CARDS
WHERE UserId = 2
```

This will return the default cards as well as the user #2 modified cards.

My question is, is there a more efficient means of doing this? My problem with the above code is that a fragment of SQL code is being run twice (SELECT ... WHERE UserId = 2) and this seems inefficient to me.

I have looked at the other set operators without success (INTERSECT, EXCEPT) and I even entertained the idea of using the MERGE operator to no avail.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: SQL data doesn't have any order, other than that specified by an `order by` clause. What are you ordering by?

Comment: How about solving it with parent Card ID which points to the original card and is null for any original card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE and ROW_NUMBER function to assign a row number (a "priority") to a record (group by records that have same CardID) and then select only the records with the highest priority (priority=1):

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT
        CardID,
        UserID,
        CardText,
        priority = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CardID ORDER BY UserID DESC)
    FROM
        dbo.Cards
    WHERE
        UserID IN (1,2)  -- filter by UserIDs of a user (UserID=2 in this example) and a "dummy user" that holds default values (UserID=1)
)

SELECT * FROM cte WHERE priority=1
```

Edit: This assumes that UserID of the "dummy" user is always lower that the UserID of the actual user (e.g. UserID of a "dummy" user is 1, actual UserID > 1).

Comment: This is perfect! exactly what I was looking for, you sir are a god!